# Laravel save retrieved value via ajax in db

Tags: jquery, ajax, json, laravel, laravel-4

I retrieve the json from the view:

```
$container.parent().find('button[name=save]').click(function () {
    alert('we are trying to save');
  $.ajax({
    url: "/laranav/public/",
    data: {"data": handsontable.getData()}, //returns all cells' data
    dataType: 'json',
    type: 'POST',
    success: function (res) { console.log(res); alert(res); }
   /* error: function () {
      $console.text('Save error. POST method is not allowed on GitHub Pages. Run this example on your own server to see the success message.');
    }*/
  });
```

Then in Routes.php

```
// here i make the view
Route::get('/', 'CustomerController@getIndex');
// here i wanna save the retrieved json
Route::post('/', 'CustomerController@postSave');
```

Now in wanna save the retrieved json in the Controller:

```
public function postSave() {
    $t = Input::get('Name');
    $c = Customer::find('DKT000142');
    $c->Name = $t;
    $c->save();
}
```

the retrieving json stuff looks like:

```
 data[0][Name]:Afrifield Corporation
 data[0][City]:Maidstone
 data[1][Name]:Amann Informatik AG
 data[1][City]:Reinach BL
 data[2][Name]:Antarcticopy
 data[2][City]:Antwerpen
 data[3][Name]:Autohaus Mielberg KG
 data[3][City]:Hamburg 36
```

This gives an error, cause im doing something wron in the postSave() func

```
POST http://127.0.0.1/laranav/public/ 500 (Internal Server Error) 
send 
x.extend.ajax
(anonymous function) 127.0.0.1/laranav/public/:77
x.event.dispatch
v.handle
```

for testing i changed the value here and it on this way it's working

```
public function getOne() {
    $c = Customer::find('DKT000142');
    $c->Name = 'Amann Informatik AG';
    $c->save();
}
```

My table class

```
 class Customer extends Eloquent {

     //The database table used by the model.
     protected $table = '7_0 - CRONUS (ai-Patches) AG$Customer';
     public $timestamps = false;
     public $primaryKey = 'No_';
     //important columns No_ | Name | City and a lot other that i don't wanna touch
  }
```

Comment: What is your table field names and in which field you have ``DKT000142``?

Comment: in No_ which also is the primarykey

Comment: By glance it looks like you're posting an array of data and `Input::get('Name');` will be null. I recommend taking a look at the XHR-request (ajax) in the browser. For chrome: ctrl+shit+i, go to the network tab and inspect your request.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Solution 1 -> if using where, then use update**

```
public function postSave() {
    $input = Input::all();
    $input = $input['data'][2]['Name'];
    Customer::where('No_','=','DKT000142')->update(array('Name' =>  $input));
    return Input::all();
}
```

**Solution 2 -> if using find, then use save**

```
public function postSave() {
    $input = Input::all();
    $input = $input['data'][2]['Name'];

    $c = Customer::find('DKT000142');
    $c->Name = $input;
    $c->save();
    return Input::all();
}
```

Comment: this getOne func, was a test func which works.. but i wanna save the a value of the retrieving json. not c->name = amann informatik instead i wanna have c->name = Input::get('Name');

Comment: Try ``$input = Input::all(); $input = $input['data'][0]; $c->Name = $input['Name']; $c->save();``

Comment: Can you say the exact and complete html respose from your request? copy this by expanding your request url in firefox.

Comment: if i return now return $input; i get in console Object{name: "name1", City: "city1"}

Comment: exactly what you are expecting?

Comment: yes but only when i make a return and i don't wanna return the retrievded json, instead i wanna save it, and if i try to save i get the error 500 like mentioned at the start.. -> saving: http://snag.gy/CuCTF.jpg

Comment: I am asking you what is the html you are getting when expanding the url seen in the last console picture.

Comment: ah sry, when i click preview in chromedevtools i get ->{"error":{"type":"Symfony\\Component\\Debug\\Exception\\FatalErrorException","message":"Call to undefined method Illuminate\\Database\\Eloquent\\Collection::save()","file":"C:\\wamp\\www\\laranav\\app\\controllers\\CustomerController.php","line":37}}

Comment: Did you got same message when you are tried with static data? ``$c->Name = 'Amann Informatik AG';``

Comment: yes in the postSave func i also get the same error with static data, but with the test func 'getOne' it worked

Comment: it's like i can't call any other function in the `postSave()` only declare variables and make a returns..

Comment: this works now like thath ` public function postSave() {
  $input = Input::all();
  $input = $input['data'][2]['Name'];

  $c = Customer::find('DKT000142');
  $c->Name = $input;
  $c->save();

 }`